# Magento 2 - insert meta data to page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, meta, reference

I need to add different meta data for different page layouts, i've tried to do it like this:

```
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="meta_og">
            <action method="setText">
                <argument translate="true" name="meta_og" xsi:type="string">
                    <![CDATA[<meta property="og:url" content="stuff.ccom" />]]>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

but its only working on a normal layout (like `default.xml`)

How can I use this to add meta for **page layouts?** (`layout/page_layout/test.xml`)

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this inside page layouts as they are only supposed to be used for wireframing the page (hence why blocks aren't allowed either, only containers). The only supported tags are:

```
<container>
<referenceContainer>
<move>
<update>
```

See the [page layout](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html) instructions for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, do you know any way to add custom meta data to each page?

Comment: If it needs to go on every page you should use `default.xml`, if it needs to be only on certain pages you'll need to add it to those layout handles such as `catalog_product_view.xml`.